# Change/navigate to specific node of a tree?

Tags: c#, algorithm, tree

I'm trying to change a specific node of a tree but I'm stumped. I know algorithms that can get and return a node in the tree, but my goal is to actually change the value of the node in that tree.

So for example, if we have a tree in which each item has a Name property of

```
Root
+Node 1
++Node 1_1
++Node 1_2
++...
+Node 2
++Node 2_1
++Node 2_2
++..
```

And I wanted to change the name of Node 1.2, I would so something like:
`Root.Node1.Node1_2.Name = "New Name";` But how would I do this programatically?
In my case, I am given the object Node 1_2, and I want to change it within the tree.

---

I forgot to mention that the data structure I am using is my own data structure that has a Parent and a List of children.

I should rephrase what I'm trying to achieve. Given the tree structure above (it can be of unlimited depth, though not illustrated), and given an arbitrary object that is known to be within the tree, how would I access the element in the tree and modify it? That is, how would I programmatically achieve something similar to: Root.Node 1.Node 1_1.Node 1_1_2.Node 1_1_2_4.Node 1_1_2_N.Name?

Let me know if there are still any confusion?

Comment: What are we talking about? TreeViews? What are you targetting: Winforms? WPF? ASP? ...?? __Always__ tag your question accordingly! - TreeNodes hava property Nodes, which has a string indexer.

Comment: @TaW Hi. No I'm just using my own data structure that has a List<T> Child and a T parent.

Comment: Well, in that case it is up to you to provide the necessary methods. The indexer of the TreeNode in my answer looks good imo, but you will have to decide if you like it. If you do, then you should implement an indexer for your node class. (I hope it is a class, not a structure ;-)

Comment: Hi @TaW What if I don't know the depth of what I'm trying to look beforehand? (Refer to my edited post)
In C++, I could just have a pointer point to the object and then modify it from there, but I can't think of good ways to do so in C#

Comment: Well, you could keep track of all Nodes by adding references in a `Dictionary<string, yourNodeClass>`. This is pretty much holding named pointers.. Of course either the names must be unique or, if you  store the full path this path must be unique. I'd go for the former, if you want to use the namig scheme in your example. Although this sounds not really tree-like, any insert would mess it up. Btw, there is not magic behind c# indexers, you can write your own; but they still have to be implemented by some search algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean `Winforms TreeViews`, each `TreeNode` has a `Nodes` property with a string [indexer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/6x16t2tx%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) you can use, **provided** you have set and know the `Node` names/keys:

```
TreeView tv = new TreeView();
tv.Nodes.Add("a", "Albert");
tv.Nodes["a"].Nodes.Add("v", "Victoria");

tv.Nodes["a"].Nodes["v"].Text = "Peggy";
```

Note that you can even change those names/keys and the new values will now work:

```
tv.Nodes["a"].Name = "Al";
tv.Nodes["Al"].Text = "Bundy";
```

Of course now the old ones won't work:

```
tv.Nodes["a"].Text = "Bud"; // <-- now throws a NullObjectReference!
```

Answer (score 1):

This is my solution I came up with, but I feel like there should be a more elegant way to do it.

```
    public static void Rename(Node the_node, string new_name)
    {
            List<Node> parent_list = new List<Node>();
            Node current_node = the_node;
            parent_list.Add(current_node);
            while (current_node.ParentNode != null)
            {
                parent_list.Add(current_node.ParentNode);
                current_node = the_node.ParentNode;
            }

            Rename(ref the_node, parent_list, new_name);
    }

    private static void Rename(ref Node target_node, List<Node> traverse_order, string new_name)
    {
        if (traverse_order.Count > 0)
        {
            Node current_node = traverse_order.Last();
            traverse_order.RemoveAt(traverse_order.Count - 1);

            EditNode(ref current_node, traverse_order);
        }
        else
        {
            target_node.Name = new_name;
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is absolutely confusing.  What is `LIsts.IndexOf` and `EditNode`?  If you already have a reference to the node that you want to change (`Node the_node` parameter in your first method) then why can you not simply change its name: `the_node.Name = new_name`?  Why are you bothering with the node's ancestors?